# "res.setHeader is not a function" error Google Auth Strategy in NestJS GraphQL

Tags: graphql, jwt, nestjs, passport.js, google-authentication

I've tried to implement an oauth method using GraphQL with Google auth and for some reason I'm getting the following error
"res.setHeader is not a function" from within the authenticate method in Google Strategy
I've used `passport-google-oauth20` strategy

this is my google-auth.guard.ts

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('google') {
    getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
        const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
        const gqlReq = ctx.getContext().req;
        if (gqlReq) {
          const { token } = ctx.getArgs();
          gqlReq.body = { token };
          return gqlReq;
        }
        return context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
      }
}
```

this is my google.strategy.ts

```
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy, VerifyCallback } from 'passport-google-oauth20';

import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Profile } from 'passport';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {

  constructor() {
    super({
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URL,
      prompt: 'consent',
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    })
  }

  async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: Profile,
    done: VerifyCallback,
  ): Promise<any> {
    if (!profile) {
      return done(new UnauthorizedException(), false);
    }
    return done(null, profile);
  }
}
```

it's important to point out that since my app is a react SPA, the callbackURL value is the main page of the client and not another path in the server.

and the resolver which I intend to use to generate a jwt token and a refresh token, but the code never gets to this part due to the error in the strategy

```
@UseGuards(GoogleAuthGuard)
@Query(() => LoginResponseApi)
async googleLogin(
    @Args({ name: 'token', type: () => String }) token: string,
    @Req() req,
    @Context() context
): Promise<LoginResponseApi> {
    const res: Response = context.req.res;

    const loginResponse: any = await this.authService.googleLogin(req)
    const jwtToken = this.authService.createRefreshToken(loginResponse.user)

    if (loginResponse.accessToken)
        this.authService.sendRefreshToken(res, jwtToken)

    return loginResponse;
}
```